# What does it mean when ^\ doesn't work, but kill -9 does?

Tags: command-line, kill, signal

Recently, I've had a third-party program hang in a weird way. It stops taking input or output, and ^C and ^\ do nothing. `kill -9` and killing the parent process *do* end it.

What state could the process be in, that SIGTERM doesn't work but SIGKILL does? And, what dangers should I be aware of when using SIGKILL like this?

Comment: Knowing the name of the application could change the answers.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It's a program called "foma"—basically a domain-specific language for defining NFAs. Mostly used in linguistics.

Comment: It's possible `Control`+`D` might work but I really don't know the program at all. I guess the bigger question isn't how to kill it but why it needs to be killed in the first place?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sadly, it's kind of a shaky, brittle program. A missing semicolon, for example, causes this type of hang, while an extra semicolon causes a segfault.

Comment: It would appear the Morphological Analysis industry is doomed :(

Answer (score 1):

Programs (and scripts) may trap and handle or ignore any signal except 9 (SIGKILL). SIGKILL is a last resort because it abrogates any exiting cleanup a program might do. The default action for any signal is to terminate the process, so you can try other numbers to see if the program handles them or gets terminated.  See the list of all possible signals with the command:

```
kill -L
```

Usually, a program will handle just a few of the 62 possibilities other than SIGKILL.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize SIGTERM could be ignored!